# Confluent kafka rest optional fields

Tags: json, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

When publishing avro payload to kafka-rest service, if one of the the field in value_schema defined with a default value, and in records omit this field. Seems kafka-rest still insist to have it inside record. What is the right way to do so?

eg.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v1+json" \
  --data '{"value_schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"User\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"int\",\"default\":18}, {\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}", "records": [{"value": {"name": "testUser", "id": "001"}}]}' \
  "http://localhost:8082/topics/avrotest"
```

Output

```
{"error_code":42203,"message":"Conversion of JSON to Avro failed: Failed to convert JSON to Avro: Expected field name not found: age"}
```